# Effects of XmlIncludeAttribue when it's used in WCF DataContract

Tags: wcf, inheritance, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer, known-types

1) Does `Binding` use while creating  [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) makes any difference to how serialization/deserialization works? (I know that binding used should match the server side binding of the service.)

I am using [KnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute in one of my `DataContract` but it does not work. But if I use [XmlIncludeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx), it works! (I am migrating my ASMX services to WCF.. But I am not using any MessageContracts since I have freedom to update client side proxies too.)

[XmlInclude(typeof(Males))]
[DataContract]
public abstract class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Name { get; set; }
}

2) If I use any Attribute ( to be specific - XmlInclude)) that uses `XmlSerializer` for the WCF `DataContract`, does WCF use `XmlSerializer` instead of `DataContractSerializer`?

Comment: This question can be closed as question is too localized. The Use of binding has no effect on the serialization/de-serialization. XmlInclude uses XmlSerializer and KnownType uses DataContractSerializer. So it's not necessary to mix the two. I needed to use KnownType correctly to get rid of the problmes.

Answer (score -1):

DataContractSerializer supports everything that XmlSerializer supports, but the reverse is not true. But if a type is decorated with [DataContract], it switches over completely to the new DataContract programming model, completely throwing away support for [Serializable], IXmlSerializable, etc. types that it otherwise would have had.

So your [XmlInclude] magic works only if you're using ASMX and the traditional XmlSerializer. If you're using DataContractSerializer, you have to do known types, and XML-isms like [XmlInclude] and XML attributes are simply not supported. You can still use XmlSerializer instead of DataContractSerializer if you want to, though; all you need to do is decorate the service or operation you want to switch over to XmlSerializer with [XmlSerializerFormatAttribute.]

Hope this helps!